# Changing the size of a node using \node rather than \draw node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to change the size of a node using `\node` rather than `\draw node`? I wrote the wrong code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [orange,minimum size=2cm] at (-5,4) {\textbullet};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The code you use does indeed change the size of the node to at least 2cm. What do you want? Please also note, that your code is not a complete minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)) as it is not compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you have changed the size of the node. But `minimum size` only sets the size of the outline of the node, which you'll see if you add `draw` to the node options:

```
\node [draw, orange,minimum size=2cm] at (-5,4) {\textbullet};
```

(Modify the `minimum size` and see that the size of the rectangle changes.)

To make the text of the node larger, set the font size (e.g. `font=\Huge`), or use `scale`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [orange] {Foo \textbullet{} bar};
    \node [orange,font=\Huge] at (0,-1) {Foo \textbullet{} bar};
    \node [orange,scale=4] at (0,-2) {Foo \textbullet{} bar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of last code]

On a different note, if your purpose was to make a big, filled circle, you should set the node shape to `circle`, and also add `fill` to the node options, but not have any text in the node. Alternatively use `\fill` with a `circle` path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [orange,minimum size=2cm,circle,fill,draw] at (-5,4) {};
    \fill [red] (-1,4) circle[radius=1cm]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Admittedly this answer is a bit of a stab in the dark, so if this doesn't answer your question I'll delete it.

Comment: Hello @TorbjørnT, why the point at (-5,4) isn't of the same size of node?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Why would it be? A `node` is a container for text, with `minimum size` you set the smallest size for this container, you don't set the  font size for the text inside the node. If your purpose is to draw a big circle there are better ways.

Comment: Ok. Thus I can't see a point as a part of a text? @ TorbjørnT

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I don't know what you mean by that, can you clarify? I updated my answer.

Comment: For example I'd like to draw/write point+text and change the size of both simultaneously (this with the only statement \node).

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Like that?